Github Actions. Deploy only modified files(PR) to FTP
Is there a way to deploy only modified file that are part of the PR (my PR contains 5 files, I want only these 4 files to be uploaded to the server).
Here is the action I'm using:
- name:  Synchronise les fichiers(check deploy4)
  uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.5
  with:
    server: ${{ secrets.FTP }}
    username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}

This yaml download everything, even if the PR contains only 4 files.
Full workflow:
name:  Deployer sur site FTP 'francois'

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - FTP_dev

jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name:  Récupère le code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name:  Synchronise les fichiers(check deploy4)
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.5
        with:
          server: ${{ secrets.FTP }}
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}


It seems there is an option on the action to exclude files, so you could eventually exclude all files that aren't among the files updated in the PR. However, given how the action works, I understand the deployment will overwrite the current files and won't keep the previous files, which may break your site. Building the whole code and deploying it will guarantee you will have what you need for your site to work every time you run this workflow.
